# Removes first element but want it to remove last element

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

In this code, I want to remove the last object from list using removeLast. But it removes 1st element. How can I remove last element using removeLast method. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

### List.java:

```
class List {

    Customer listPtr;
    int index;

    public void add(Customer customer) {
        Customer temp = customer;
        if (listPtr == null) {
            listPtr = temp;
            index++;
        } else {
            Customer x = listPtr;
            while (x.next != null) {
                x = x.next;
            }
            x.next = temp;
            index++;
        }
    }

    public void removeLast() {
        Customer temp = listPtr;
        if (listPtr != null) {
            listPtr = temp.next;
        }
    }

    public void removeAll() {
        Customer temp = listPtr;
        while (temp != null) {
            listPtr = temp.next;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        int size = 0;
        Customer temp = listPtr;
        while (temp != null) {
            size++;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        return size;
    }

    public void printList() {
        Customer temp = listPtr;
        while (temp != null) {
            System.out.println(temp);
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
}
```

---

### DemoList.java:

```
class DemoList {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List list = new List();
        Customer c1 = new Customer("10011", "Jason");
        Customer c2 = new Customer("10012", "George");
        Customer c3 = new Customer("10013", "Sam");
        list.add(c1);
        list.add(c2);
        list.add(c3);
        list.removeLast();

        list.printList();

    }
}
```

---

### Customer.java:

```
class Customer {

    String id;
    String name;
    Customer next;

    public Customer(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return id + " : " + name;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object ob) {
        Customer c = (Customer) ob;
        return this.id.equals(c.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question title "algorithm in Java" was terribly non-informative. I've tried to correct it, and please feel free to correct my correction, but also please do a better job next time by putting more effort into creating an informative helpful title that keys folks here to the essence of your problem. Doing this will help you get better, quicker help.

Comment: You should probably post your `Customer` class as well, so we can understand what the instance field `next` means exactly and how it's initialized for each instance of `Customer`.

Comment: @Mena The Customer class is at the bottom.

Comment: @NutterzUK yep, OP posted right after I commented.

Comment: Doesn't this code remove all but the first element?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The issue is that you need to get the element which is not last, but second to last. This way you can tell that element that it's "next" is null.

The following code can probably be improved, but this solution will work for you.

```
public void removeLast() {
    Customer temp = listPtr;  
    while(temp.next.next!=null){
        temp = temp.next;
    } 
    temp.next=null;   
}
```

Comment: NPE when list.size() = 1. Should decrement the `index` too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of the second to last element as well

```
public void removeLast() {
    if (listPtr != null) {
      Customer x1 = listPtr;
      Customer x2 = listPtr;
      while (x2.next != null) {
        x1 = x2;
        x2 = x2.next;
      }
      x1.next = null; // delete last
      index--;
    }
}
```

Your current code is effectively just moving the pointer one up down the list

```
    Customer temp = listPtr;
    if (listPtr != null) {
        listPtr = temp.next; // point to second element
    }
```